# How do you capture a JSP rendering into a String using Spring Boot 2 (Spring 5 + Tomcat 9)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, rendering

I've implemented the SwallowingHttpServletResponse example that is available in various examples online. It has worked for me in the past when I was using Spring 4 and Tomcat 7, but now that I have migrated to using Spring Boot 2 (which uses Spring 5 and embedded Tomcat 9) capturing the JSP rendering doesn't seem to work anymore. Does anybody know how to get the SwallowingHttpServletResponse example to work with a Spring Boot 2 (Spring 5 + Tomcat 9) web application?

Code example that works with Spring 4 + Tomcat 7:

- https://technologicaloddity.com/2011/10/04/render-and-capture-the-output-of-a-jsp-as-a-string/
- https://www.javatips.net/api/CaptureJSP-master/src/main/java/com/technologicaloddity/capturejsp/util/SwallowingJspRenderer.java

Comment: *"available in various examples online"* Where? Show links, so we can be sure to look at the same examples you based your code on. You should also consider showing your code.

Comment: @Andreas links added to the description

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem. After upgrading to Spring 5 and Tomcat 8.5 my internal jsp rendering method stopped working. It turned out I was not defining the request method (as GET) in the mock request. This may have been defaulted in the past? Haven't spent too much time looking into it...

Anyway, here's the code:

Service:

```
@Service
public class JspService implements ServletContextAware {

    private InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver;

    @Autowired
    public void setViewResolver(InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver) {
        this.viewResolver = viewResolver;
    }

    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.context = servletContext;
    }

    public String renderJspView(String viewName, ModelMap modelMap) throws Exception {

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/" + viewName + ".jsp");
        View view = viewResolver.resolveViewName(viewName, Locale.US);

        MockHttpServletResponse mockResp = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        HttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        JspRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new JspRequestWrapper(mockRequest, requestDispatcher);
        mockResp.flushBuffer(); // important! forces servlet include

        view.render(modelMap, requestWrapper, mockResp);

        return mockResp.getContentAsString();
    }
}
```

Request Wrapper

```
public class JspRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher;

    public JspRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        this.requestDispatcher = requestDispatcher;
    }


    @Override
    public RequestDispatcher getRequestDispatcher(String path) {
        return requestDispatcher;
    }

    // Hardcode contextPath and URI so links work
    @Override
    public String getContextPath() {
        return "https://foo.bar.com/<webapp name>";
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestURI() {
        return "foo.bar.com";
    }

    // Define request method!
    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return "GET";
    }
}
```